# deleting rows two days after the earliest date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE public.mylog
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('mylog_id_seq'::regclass),
  userid text,
  insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT mylog_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT mylog_userid_unique UNIQUE (userid)
)
```

Let's assume the earliest row has the `insert_time` as "2017-02-24 00:00:00.064049+00"

How can I delete all rows that contain the earliest insert_time and one day after that. In our case, the query would delete rows that were inserted on 2017-02-24 and on 2017-02-25

Answer (score 0):

The strategy of this approach is to find the earliest insertion *date* using a subquery, and then delete all records whose date is less than this earliest date plus two days.  In the case of your sample data, `insert_time::date` should yield `'2017-02-24'` and therefore anything less than `'2017-02-26'` should be targeted for deletion.

```
DELETE
FROM public.mylog
WHERE insert_time < (SELECT MIN(insert_time::date) FROM public.mylog) + INTERVAL '2 days'
```

Answer (score 0):

DELETE
FROM public.mylog
WHERE insert_time < NOW() * 60 * 60 * 48

Comment: This is invalid for Postgres. There is no `time()` function